# Is there a way to have 'Inside End' and 'Outside End' labels on a single axis Excel bar chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a dashboard with a typical bar chart that only has 'Inside End' labels on it (percentages usually). This dashboard is can vary depending on which variable I pick (i.e. if I pick a different city, the bar chart percentages will change for that specific city).

However, sometimes changing a variable will output a bar chart with a very small percentage, making it very hard to fit or see the 'Inside End' label.

Is it possible to be able to make those specific cases an 'Outside End' label, whilst having the rest of the bars that are visible in the chart 'Inside End'?

Let me know if I can make this question clearer.

EDIT: Some people have asked for a screenshot, hopefully this link works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ErDI.jpg

Comment: A sample data/chart will help.. ( :

Comment: Adding a couple of screenshots would help. (Upload them to imgur and paste the links into your question.)

Comment: duplicate your series, change fill colour and border to 'no fill' one seris can have inside, the other can have outside end labels,

Comment: You can also create a macro that would check the percentage value of each bar and programmatically set inside/outside labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to be able to make those specific cases an 'Outside End' label

AFAIK, automatically? No. IMHO, I'll do it manually though, in two possible ways :

1. To scale the max y-axis to 70% instead of the applied 100% >> this will make  all Inside end % visible.
2. Or, proceed with Inside End option. Select the only the 'misaligned' percentage label, then move it manually. Apply different color if needed.

That works for me. Eg. [here](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/EeZaqxmw9qFHmTAKZCtiVbMB-FlWMlx8oK6hyzC7z0cq4g?e=yii3sP)